# Cannot create a woocommerce search based on custom meta fields

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, metadata

I try to include in my default search custom fields. I followed the link here

http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/

I created a small plugin from it which gets my custom select field and custom text and I have the following

```
<?php
/**
* Add sku, author, publisher and format to product search
*/

// hook into wp pre_get_posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'jc_woo_search_pre_get_posts');

/**
* Add custom join and where statements to product search query
* @param  mixed $q query object
* @return void
*/
function jc_woo_search_pre_get_posts($q){

if ( is_search() ) {
    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'jc_search_post_join' );
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'jc_search_post_excerpt' );
} 
}

/**
* Add Custom Join Code for wp_mostmeta table
* @param  string $join
* @return string
*/
function jc_search_post_join($join = ''){

global $wp_the_query;

// escape if not woocommerce searcg query
if ( empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) || empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
        return $join;

$join .= "INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS jcmt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = jcmt1.post_id)";
return $join;
}

/**
* Add custom where statement to product search query
* @param  string $where
* @return string
*/
function jc_search_post_excerpt($where = ''){

global $wp_the_query;

// escape if not woocommerce search query
if ( empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) || empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
        return $where;

$where = preg_replace("/post_title LIKE ('%[^%]+%')/", "post_title LIKE $1)
            OR (jcmt1.meta_key = '_sku' AND CAST(jcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1)
            OR  (jcmt1.meta_key = '_text_field' AND CAST(jcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1)
            OR  (jcmt1.meta_key = '_select' AND CAST(jcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1 ", $where);

return $where;
}
?>
```

But nothing happens how can I fix this
thank you

Comment: @Loic Maybe you can help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is much simple code and just paste it in your functions.php file.

```
function woo_custom_search( $query ) {

if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    if ( $query->is_search() ) { 

        $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'custom_field_name',
            'value'     => $query->query['s'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'  
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

    }

 }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query' , 'woo_custom_search' );
```

**Reference:**

[woocommerce_product_query](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Query.html#403)

Comment: It's working fine for me. You may need to modify that in order to work in your end.